# Command tlmgr not working in Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: packages, texlive, ubuntu

I've installed (in Ubuntu 14.04) not full version of TeX Live (cause the full version is very large).

When I'm trying to install some packages using `tlmgr` I'm getting a message

> "(running on Debian, switching to user mode!)".

I've read that it's a error in Ubuntu, so is there any way to fix this problem?

Comment: No: if you install TeX Live/Debian, `tlmgr` can only install packages for the single user. This is because of Debian restrictions on how software can be installed.

Comment: And how to install packages for the single user?

Comment: read the manual of tlmgr with man tlmgr or tlmgr --help and especially the section on user mode.